# SSRS 2005: printing issue - report prints first page in portrait and rest are landscape

Tags: reporting-services, printing, reportingservices-2005

my environment is SQL 2005, SSRS 2005 , .net 2.0

Client is experiencing following issue on two different printers. ( Canon and Lanier LD140).

We have a report which is designed as landscape report.

When report is send to print,
First page is rendered in portrait  mode(cutting of the information on the right side. )

rest of the pages print in landscape mode.

did anyone have similar issue and knows how to fix it so first page gets printed in landscape mode?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We tried printing on other printers and it worked fine.
Issue was later resolved for printers in questions by updating their printer drivers.